# Fingerprint Scanner Problem with Samsung C5

Tags: samsung

I have bought Samsung C5 recently. The mobile phone is very nice and slim to work with. But yesterday I was trying to configure my finger print on it for biometric security. I tried repeatedly on it but it is not scanning my thumb? Can anyone please help me regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is really simple. This model comes with a front end fingerprint scanner that doesn`t cover up the area of your thumb. So while scanning for biometric registration, you have to slide your thumb from top to bottom to get it done rightly. As a tip, try to clean your thumb before biometric registration.

Comment: that solved the problem. thanks mate